# Inconveniente con formulario usando nav-tabs y EJS

Tags: html, nodejs, bootstrap, ejs

espero puedan darme luces con este inconveniente:

He estado tratando de crear un formulario con multiples tabs usando bootstrap(nav nav-pills).
Estoy usando EJS como motor de plantillas. He creado formularios en partials para luego solo llamarlos en la navegación de los nav-pills.
Todo me funciona perfecto a excepción de cuando navegas en los tabs, lo que hace es que se muestra un formulario encima del otro(se sobrepone). [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<%- layout('layouts/main') %>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane active show" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
      <%- include('partials/datos_personales'); %>
    </div>  

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab"> 
      <%- include('partials/datos_laboral'); %>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Espero me puedan asistir, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una posible solución.
aún no logro ejecutarlo con la plantilla EJS, pero mas o menos sería de esa manera.

```js
$("#pills-home-tab").click(function() {
    $("#datos_personales_form").show();
    $("#datos_laborales_form").hide(); })

    $("#pills-profile-tab").click(function() {
    $("#datos_laborales_form").show();
    $("#datos_personales_form").hide();
})
```

```css
#datos_laborales_form{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- CSS Scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#personal_info" role="tab"
        aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="false">Datos Personales</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#laboral_info" role="tab"
        aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Datos Laborales</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<form method="post" id="datos_personales_form">
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <!-- 1ra fila -->
                        <div class="form-group col">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombres" autofocus required>
                            <label for="nombres">Nombres</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidos" required>
                            <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
                
<form method="post" id="datos_laborales_form">
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <!-- 1ra fila -->
                        <div class="form-group col">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cargo" autofocus required>
                            <label for="cargo">Cargo</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Salario" required>
                            <label for="Salario">Salario</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nikos_solis/qhkamj3x/19/)